# MSTest-Cross browser testing C# with Selenium?-how to run C# Selenium tests against multiple browsers

Tags: selenium, webdriver, c#, cross-browser-testing

At the moment my tests are running only in Firefox, because that is the driver which initialize at last. I need to run my tests on both Firefox and Chrome. Parallel or serially. But it should be automatic.

Below is my example test-code:.

```
namespace TestOne
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void BeforeEveryTest()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void NavigateToGoogle()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void RunAfterEveryTest()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

What are the options to run this test for both Chrome and Firefox? When using the C# testing tools (e.g. mstest.exe or vstest.console.exe)

Comment: Changed the question a bit to make it a bit more clear, not sure why this is being voted as unclear. The question is simple, how to run C# Selenium tests against multiple browsers.

Comment: It is almost funny that question from member of "closing mafia" is almost closed by "closing mafia".

Comment: I got the error NullReferenceException when using TestContext.Properties["browser"].ToString() on BaseClass. Could you have any oter solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a `.RunSettings` as described in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <TestRunParameters>
    <Parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
  </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

If you make a file for Firefox and Chrome you can run the tests from the command-line with [VStest.Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) like this:

```
vstest.console myTestDll.dll /Settings:Chrome.RunSettings /Logger:trx
vstest.console myTestDll.dll /Settings:Firefox.RunSettings /Logger:trx
```

Your test would look like this:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeEveryTest()
    {
        if ( TestContext.Properties["browser"].ToString() == "chrome" ) {
          driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else {
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
    }
```

Comment: in here every time i have to change the browser name by editing the .RunSettings file.But i want it to be get automatically .One browser after another.

Comment: You make two run setting files. Add the two commands to a batch or powershell script. Then execute that one script to run them after each other.